# AppCode warning about a C-style array in an Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, c, appcode

```
@implementation MonthView {
    DayView *dayViews[6][7];
}
```

Xcode does not complain about this code, but AppCode gives a warning:

> Pointer to non-const type 'DayView * * const * ' with no explicit lifetime

My intention was to create a 6x7 block of DayView pointers that will be part of the memory layout of any MonthView instance.

Is this code doing what I want, and how can I fix this warning?

Comment: Are you compiling with the ARC setting on?

Comment: Where does this warning occur?

Comment: On the second line of the snippet, beginning with DayView...

Comment: The construct looks legitimate. My guess is that it's a bug in the AppCode. I tried a 2D array of `id` objects with `dealloc`, and verified that ARC handles them correctly.

Comment: `NSArray` would be an improvement in most scenarios… I can't think of one instance of this form in my codebase (that still exists).

Comment: This is indeed a bug, please follow and vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-3244

Comment: @AntonMakeev: Thanks for the verification.  As your response is the correct answer, I would be happy to give you credit if you post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do is valid, but if the comments above are correct and this is due to a bug in AppCode and the warning you receive throws a wrench into the works (such as when using *-Werror*) or it just bothers you to receive it, you can get around it by just allocating the array inside *-init*.

*Fair warning: This code is off the top of my head and I don't guarantee it to work as written.*

```
@implementation MonthView { 
     DayView ***dayViews;
}

@interface MonthView
     - (id)init {
          if ((self = [super init])) {
               int i;

               // do stuff here

               // Create the array
               dayViews = malloc(sizeof(id) * 6);
               dayViews[0] = malloc(sizeof(DayView *) * 6 * 7);

               for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                    dayViews[i] = dayViews[0] + (i * 7);
               }
          }

          return self;
     }
@end
```

This code should produce a two-dimensional array that you can access as normal, while minimizing the number of calls to malloc needed.